# sending automatic push notifications in app from web service

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i have made an android app for buying and selling of goods. Now i want to send notifications to all the users everyday regarding how many new items have been added. I have used php language for scripting.

I went through various sites but am confused.. Is using google cloud messaging service (GCM) necessary? will it send automatic notifications everyday?

I am confused. please help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say yes to the GCM in your case if you can have your own third party server running somewhere. The server can use GCM to talk to all devices running your app. The advantage here is that non of the app installations on many devices need to be connected to your server for this to happen. No background `Service`/`IntentService` running draining battery.

[Read all about GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and Study the client/server demo and you're up and running in a few days.